# New site conf file for Apache 2.4.6

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I had just upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10 earlier today. The version of Apache2 is 2.4.6 now. I removed the old site config file and tried to create a new one. When I was trying to copy default.conf, I found the format had been changed significantly. And here is an example of the new conf file. As lots of people do, I also have the forbidden problem even if I set my folder permission to 777.

```
      1 <VirtualHost *:80>
      2     # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port th    at
      3     # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
      4     # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
      5     # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
      6     # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
      7     # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
      8     # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
      9     ServerName www.janicezhang.me
     10 
     11     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
     12     DocumentRoot /home/yifan/www/janice
     13 
     14     # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
     15     # error, crit, alert, emerg.
     16     # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
     17     # modules, e.g.
     18     #LogLevel info ssl:warn
     19 
     20     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     21     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
     22 
     23     # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
     24     # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
     25     # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
     26     # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
     27     # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
     28     #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
     29 </VirtualHost>
```

I am just wondering if there is some toturial to set up virtual host for apache 2.4.6 in ubuntu 13.10. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I solved the problem by myself. Two things need to be done. 
First, add lines in your site config file like this:

```
<Directory "/home/yifan/www/janice">
    Options ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After this, I can browse into the site without the forbidden error. However, the php file is displayed as plain text. I check the folder mods-enabled and find php5 is not here. I have no idea why php5 is lost during upgrading. So just reinstall it by

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

Then, the site is recovered.

Comment: You mean to say, we should add the Directory tag ourselves? I am having the same issue and the java based website is appearing as plain text. For the previous version of apache that is 2.2.22, there are 3 Directory tags which I need to set in the new version of default.conf. It would be really great if you update your answer explaining the new changes/additions in default.conf for 2.4.6 version.

Comment: @engineer Yes, the default does not have a <Directory> tag. So, I think you have to add one by hand.