# Laravel blank white screen

Tags: php, apache, frameworks, laravel, laravel-4

My Laravel site was working before, I recently upgraded to Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.5.7.

Now I'm getting a white blank screen when I go to `laravel.mydomain.example`, nothing in Apache error logs, routes and etc. should be fine as it worked before.

`.htaccess` is loading as I get a 500 when I insert an invalid line to `/var/sites/laravel/public/.htaccess`.

Heres my `.htaccess`:

```
$ cat /var/sites/laravel/public/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Heres my virtual host directive:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/sites/laravel/public"
ServerName laravel.mydomain.example
<Directory "/var/sites/laravel/public">
    AllowOverride All
    allow from all
    Options +Indexes
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And apachectl -S

```
$ /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:*                    is a NameVirtualHost
     default server mydomain.example (/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:25)
     port * namevhost mydomain.example (/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:25)
     port * namevhost laravel.mydomain.example (/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-     vhosts.conf:34)
ServerRoot: "/usr/local/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/usr/local/apache2/logs/error_log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/usr/local/apache2/logs/" mechanism=default
PidFile: "/usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="daemon" id=1 not_used
Group: name="daemon" id=1 not_used
```

Comment: try and put a blank new install of Laravel in laravel.mydomain.com - does it work then?

Comment: HMM,I tried to create project with composer and I'm appearantly missing openssl. Is there any easy way to add it afterwards or do I need to recompile my PHP with current configure options + --with-openssl?

Comment: I was having this blank screen problem when moving an already working project onto a staging server. I was getting nowhere with it then I decided to do the same as @the-shift-exchange's suggestion and create a fresh install of Laravel, then I found the problem pretty quickly; the staging server was running an outdated version of PHP. Laravel requires at least PHP v5.4.0. Thought I'd mention it incase anyone else had the same trouble.

Comment: Check the memory limit isn't being hit - this has caused WSOD for me before in Laravel 4

Comment: Just another data point - I hit this on an an app deployed to Kubernetes, using NFS to mount the web files. Due to very slow NFS performance, it seemed Laravel was failing to cache the views within a reasonable amount of time. PHP-FPM was returning an empty response. Fixed by manually removing all views and re-caching them.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

### Apache

Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481660/403-error-on-apache-for-a-laravel-project-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-13-10/19482358#19482358) describe or help your situation? Upgrading to Apache 2.4 come with some changes in Apache configuration.

### Laravel

Are you checking Laravel's logs or Apache's logs?

Since upgrading to Laravel 4.1, I've had white screen "errors" (WSOD) when the application could not write to the log location. I've always solved this by making the app/storage directory writable by Apache (either group writable to "www-data", "apache" or world-writable - that depends on your server setup.

#### Web Server User

On Ubuntu/Debian servers, your PHP may be running as user "www-data". On CentOS/RedHat/Fedora servers, you PHP may be running as user "apache".

Make sure your files are owned by the user that is running PHP:

```
# Debian/Ubuntu
$ sudo chown -R www-data /path/to/laravel/files

# CentOS/RedHat/Fedora
$ sudo chown -R apache /path/to/laravel/files
```

> Note that you might not be running as user www-data or apache. It depends on your hosting and setup!

#### Laravel 4

```
# Group Writable (Group, User Writable)
$ sudo chmod -R gu+w app/storage

# World-writable (Group, User, Other Writable)
$ sudo chmod -R guo+w app/storage
```

#### Laravel 5+ (including 6)

```
# Group Writable (Group, User Writable)
$ sudo chmod -R gu+w storage

# World-writable (Group, User, Other Writable)
$ sudo chmod -R guo+w storage

#####
# The bootstrap/cache directory may need writing to also
##

# Group Writable (Group, User Writable)
$ sudo chmod -R gu+w bootstrap/cache

# World-writable (Group, User, Other Writable)
$ sudo chmod -R guo+w bootstrap/cache
```

Comment: Seems like it was a permission problem. chmodding the laravel directory made it work.

Comment: @fideloper This answer really saved my day. Was getting WSOD, and nothing showing up in logs anywhere. chmodding the app/storage took care of it. I tip my virtual hat to you!

Comment: Yeah thank you for this really saved me here. I was getting a X-pad: avoid browser bug in my http response and I thought it was that

Comment: Had the same problem on Nginx. Adding write-permissions to this folder solved the problem for me.

Comment: Permission on storage folder solved my such issue. But why laravel doesn't show permission issue on browser?

Comment: It's likley something to do with timing - Logging errors to the log happens after Laravel turns off displaying raw PHP errors but before it's able to turn on error handling (converting all errors to exceptions and displaying the exceptions gracefully). It's a "chicken and the egg" type problem.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me too.... would never have found this on my own. I agree it would be best if there was some sort of error message displayed rather than the "white screen of death".

Comment: Don't forget +x for your directories. Somehow that got lost on my laravel/bootstrap folder.

Comment: On Digital Ocean Ubuntu 14.04 Apache, later works fine.

Comment: The `chmod` command solved my problem. I'm using Laravel 5.4 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Saved me as well. Oddly though, this wasn't after any sort of upgrade (PHP version or otherwise) -- it seemed to happen randomly on a homestead local copy of laravel. Why would the storage directory's permissions change seemingly on a whim?

Comment: This works to me. I was getting this error becouse i've cloned the machine and do not re run this commands.

Comment: This did it: sudo chown -R www-data

Comment: For me everything worked fine and suddenly the website shows blank page, permissions to the folders are already given.

Answer (score 67):

An update to fideloper's answer for Laravel 5 and its new file structure is:

```
$ sudo chmod -R o+w storage/
```

Comment: Kudos! Solved my issue for L5 on ubuntu 14.04 server.

Comment: Worked for me as well, on Mac OS X 10.10.3

Comment: Worked for me - CentOS 6.8 (Final)

Answer (score 33):

Try this, in the public/index.php page

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Comment: This was actually what I needed because for some reason on the server work has (Plesk) it was not logging anything to the error log and nothing to the laravel log, adding this showed me that it was actually a missing file that was causing my blank 500 screen, thanks a bunch!

Comment: I had white screen also and no errors at all. All permission and everything were perfect. This answer helped me to actually see what is going on. Thanks.

Comment: have messed up with this issue since yesterday. Beyond folders' permission in my case this check was reported that the server hasn't extracted all folders inside vendor folder !? What a mystery.... Really a good approach.Useful for public servers without low access.

Comment: my case it does not work still showing strange blank screen

Comment: This gave me actionable errors, I was missing `composer install`

Comment: Thanks to this I was able to find that my PHP version was wrong and had to change it on my shared hosting.

Answer (score 29):

The following steps solved blank white screen problem on my Laravel 5.

- Go to your Laravel root folder
- Give write permission to `bootstrap/cache` and `storage` directories

> sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache storage

- Rename `.env.example` to `.env`
- Generate application key with the following command in terminal/command-prompt from Laravel root:

> php artisan key:generate

This will generate the encryption key and update the value of `APP_KEY` in `.env` file

This should solve the problem.

If the problem still exists, then update `config/app.php` with the new key generated from the above artisan key generate command:

> `'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomString'),`
>
> to
>
> `'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'KEY_GENERATED_FROM_ABOVE_COMMAND'),`

Answer (score 15):

for anyone who get blank page even after making storage accessible for displaying errors put these two lines at first lines of public/index.php to see what is happening at least. for me this error was there :Class 'PDO' not found in /var/www/***/config/database.php on line 16

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 11):

I have also one more option why blank page issue may occur. If you are on production mode and if you cached your config files by php artisan (config:cache), try to delete cache file executing:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

or delete it manualy (bootstrap/cache/config.php)

Comment: I tried everything else and this is the final thing that worked for me.

Comment: Turns out my env file was invalid, running this command let me know.

Answer (score 11):

In general if **Laravel** showing you white page without error first thing looking in the `.evn` file for error my wrong was.

The problem was in .env file in `APP_NAME`

Just i replaced

```
APP_NAME=My Project Name
```

to

```
APP_NAME="My Project Name"
```

Comment: This is the answer that saved my huge time I believe!
===> "In general if Laravel showing you white page without error first thing looking in the .evn file for error my wrong was."

Answer (score 8):

Running this command solved it for me:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

I guess a blank error page was some how cached. Had to clear the caches.

Answer (score 7):

When I was new to Linux.I usually found this error with my Laravel Project.
White errors means error, It may have some permission issue or error.

You just have to follow two steps, and will work like champ :)

(1) Give the permission. Run these command from root directory of your project

```
(a) sudo chmod 777 -R storage
(b) sudo chmod bootstrap/cache
```

(2) If you cloned the project or pulled from github then run

```
composer install
```

(3) Configure your .env file properly, and your project will work.

Comment: Step (2) was missing from my installation.  I had cloned the project thinking it had all of the necessary files in the directory for it to work out of the box.  I still had trouble, but this was a crucial step.

Answer (score 7):

Facing the blank screen in Laravel 5.8. Every thing seems fine with both storage and bootstrap folder given 777 rights. On

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

It shows the problem it was the **White spaces** in **App Name of .env** file

Answer (score 6):

It took me almost 2 hour to solve this problem.
These are reasons find out in answers:

- Remove space in .env file
- Rewrite .htaccess
- chmod 777 storage / bootstrap folder
- Remove `vendor` folder and run `composer install` again
- Restart apache/nginx server
- `php artisan view:clear`
- `php artisan cache:clear`
- `php artisan route:clear`

I tried everything but it still doesn't working.

Turn out the default port for apache/nginx server is not PORT 80. When you installed webpack, it may be changed because of corrupting with Skype or system services.
So instead of access to `yoursite.test` on `localhost`, you must use `yoursite.test:85` which 85 is the default PORT of apache/nginx server.

Answer (score 5):

I was struggling with a similar issue on a CentOS server. Using php artisan serv and accessing it through port 8000 on the local machine worked fine but could not get my remote machines to load a particular view. I could return strings fine, and some views were loading. Chased my tail on permissions for a while before I finally realized it was an SELinux issue. I just set it from enforce to permissive and it worked. Hope that helps someone else out there that may be encountering the same issue.

```
setenforce permissive
```

Comment: This helped me every time

Answer (score 5):

In my case , I have installed `laravel` many times, and I am sure that the folder write permission has been correctly given.

Like most of the answers above :

```
sudo chmod 777 -R storage bootstrap
```

The mistake is that my nginx configuration comes from the [**official documentation**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/deployment#server-configuration).

I only modified the domain name after copying ，then I got a blank page.
I tried restarting `nginx` and `php-fpm`,but not work for me.

Finally, I added this line configuration to solve the problem.

```
location ~ \.php$ {

    # same as documentation ...

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

I hope I can help others.

Comment: I lost an entire day off to this issue. This is answer that finally saved me. I wish I could give you more than an up vote. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Blank screen also happens when your Laravel app tries to display too much information and PHP limits kick in (for example displaying tens of thousands of database records on a single page). The worst part is, you won't see any errors in the Laravel logs. You probably won't see any errors in the PHP FPM logs as well. You might find errors in your http server logs, for example nginx throws something like `FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of XXX bytes exhausted`.

Short tip: add `->limit(1000)` where `1000` is your limit, on your query object.

Comment: I've been trying to solve this problem without luck until I read this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It shows the problem it was the White spaces in App Name of .env file

Answer (score 2):

I have some issues to setup it in a Vagrant machine. Whats really works for me was execute a:

`chmod -R o+w app/storage/`

from inside the Vagrant machine.

<sub>Reference: https://laracasts.com/lessons/vagrant-and-laravel</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Another thing that may cause the WSOD is missing the 'return' keyword, as in:

`return View::make('yourview');`

as opposed to

`View::make('yourview');`

Answer (score 2):

use this **.htaccess** to solve

```
Options +ExecCGI
addhandler x-httpd-php5-cgi .php
Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

There might be a lot of reasons behind the blank screen without errors.
I have faced this problem many times whenever I want to upload laravel project in shared hosting.

**Reason: Incorrect PHP Version**

In my case, issue was because of incorrect php version. I had php 7.1 version in local computer where as in shared hosting cpanel, there was php 5.6 version. Switching up the version from 5.6 to 7.1 worked for me.

You can change php version in cpanel from multiphp manager available in cpanel home page.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that there are no typos in your .env file.  This was the cause of a blank screen with me.

Nothing got logged to screen nor logfiles or nginx logs.  Just a blank screen.

Comment: Thankyou so much...there was a type issue in the .env file you helped me alot

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's because laravel 5.1 require PHP >= 5.5.9. Update php will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Strange for me, but in my case I had to clear the laravel's cache to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same issue after doing `composer update`

I tried installing `composer required monolog/monolog` too but didn't work.

**Then I removed the /vendor directory and ran `composer install` and worked as per normal.**

basically it must have reverted my monolog and other stable packages version back to previous. so better not to `composer update`

what I noticed comparing both the /vendor folders and found those `classes` files under `/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Handler` were missing after composer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes in route.php you may have

```
Route::get('/{id}', 'Controller@show'..
```

written before

```
Route::get('/add', 'Controller@add'..
```

It can be empty method `Controller::show()` when you begin to develop your controller from scratch. In this case you will get empty blank page when requesting `/add` url. It happens because the request was handled by `/{id}` route, and its method returns nothing.

Just try to place `/add` route before `/{id}`

Answer (score 0):

Other problem with the same behavior is use Laravel 3 with PHP 5.5.x. You have to change some laravel function's name "yield() because is a reserved word in php 5.5

Answer (score 0):

Reason can be `Middleware` if you forget to put following code to the end of `handle` function

```
return $next($request);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting same error when I start first time on laravel + Ubuntu 14.04
I just right click on bootstrap and storage folder >>> properties >>>permission>> Others Access >>> change it to "Create and delete files" Change permission for enclosed files

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Got this from the Laravel forums, but if you recently upgraded Laravel versions AND PHP versions AND are running nginx, make sure you have changed your nginx configuration file to reflect the new PHP version. For instance:

In your nginx site config file (here: /etc/nginx/sites-available), change

`fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;`

to

`fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;`

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. I already change chmod folder for Storage folder. fill database settings in .env, but didn't fix the problem.
I used Laravel 5.5 and I used PHP 5.6, to fix it I went to (cpanel->PHP Selector) and I changed to PHP 7.1 And the issue is done.

Answer (score 0):

On normal cases errors should be logged **Unless**

Script can't write to log file

- check it's path
- permissions

Or error occurred on higher level check app server logs like Appache || Nginx

Or it's resources limits 
Like PHP ini settings

```
memory_limit
max_input_time
max_execution_time
```

Or OS limit's and so on

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Permission problems in storage and cache folder and php version issues, there could be another reasons to display blank page without any error message.

For example, I had a **redeclare** error message without any log and with blank white page.
There was a conflict between my own helper function and a vendor function.

I suggest as **a starting point**, run `artisan` commands. for example:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

If there was a problem, it will prompted in terminal and you've got a **Clue** and you can google for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem when I tried to run a Laravel 5.8 app on my server, uploading from local development using Vagrant Homestead. After a while I figured out that the dev subdomain on the live server I was running was somehow set to PHP 5.6.

**cPanel > MultiPHP Manager > Set to PHP 7.2**

fixed this for me. Hope this might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the BLANK WHITE SCREEN issue was as simple as a typo or wrong character on the env file.
I was implementing socialite, so when I was setting up the .env credentials for Google+ like this:

```
G+_CLIENT_ID = Your G+ Client ID
G+_CLIENT_SECRET = Your G+ Client secret
G+_REDIRECT = 'http://localhost:8000/callback/google'
```

But, the .env file can't use the '+' sign, so I have to make this correction:

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = Your G+ Client ID
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = Your G+ Client secret
GOOGLE_REDIRECT = 'http://localhost:8000/callback/google'
```

I hope this help you find a dumb error...

Answer (score -2):

In my case, restarting apache fixed the problem.
for Ubuntu / Debian:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score -2):

This changes works for my localhost Ubuntu server 14.xx setting

```
# Apply all permission to the laravel 5.x site folders     
$ sudo chmod -R 777 mysite
```

Also made changes on site-available httpd setting [Apache2 settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481660/403-error-on-apache-for-a-laravel-project-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-13-10/19482358#19482358)

Add settings:

```
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
Require all granted
```

Comment: In a web server, it is not advisable to set ‘777’ permission for your files and folders as it allows anyone to add malicious code to your server. However, in some cases, you will need to set the 777 permissions before you can upload any file to the server (For example, uploading images in WordPress) https://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/