# Laravel default page blank

Tags: laravel, wsod

No error in /var/log/apache2/error.log.
I installed laravel using composer.

"msg" is my application name.
When I access localhost/msg/ , I can see the following listing:

```
[   ]   CONTRIBUTING.md 2014-01-18 18:14    145  
[DIR]   app/    2014-01-18 18:14     -   
[   ]   artisan 2014-01-18 18:14    2.4K     
[DIR]   bootstrap/  2014-01-18 18:14     -   
[   ]   composer.json   2014-01-18 18:14    697  
[   ]   composer.lock   2014-01-23 10:06     53K     
[   ]   phpunit.xml 2014-01-18 18:14    566  
[DIR]   public/ 2014-01-18 18:14     -   
[   ]   readme.md   2014-01-18 18:14    1.8K     
[   ]   server.php  2014-01-18 18:14    519  
[DIR]   vendor/ 2014-01-23 10:06     -
```

When I access localhost/msg/public/ , I get a blank page (no source code). Still no arror in the apache log.

All I did, other than the installer through composer, was a git init in the msg folder.

Any idea ? I'm really confused about not having error anywhere.

Comment: Try running "php artisan serve" to start the web server only for development purposes. Can you access `localhost:8000`? It should display laravels splash page.

Comment: @marcanuy I get the You just arrived logo ! ... but does it mean I can only run Laravel on decidated server were I can run application ? I was hopping to be able to run a php-only application on a regular hosting setup...

Comment: Is it possible that no route match because of the /msg/public/ part of the path, and somehow laravel don't throw a 404 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678360/laravel-blank-white-screen). Also remember to check the Laravel logs for errors in addition to Apache error logs (`app/storage/logs`)

Comment: @fideloper not a duplicate since I don't have an error. But thanks for pointing our the storage logs

Comment: Cool. Still worth making sure `app/storage` files are writable by PHP! That's the cause of WSOD's for me 99% of the time for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some things to verify:

Try running

```
php artisan serve
```

to start the web server only for development purposes. You should have access to

`localhost:8000`

If it does not display Laravel's splash page, then there can be a problem with Composer.
If it display the splash page, it could be

- Apache configuration
- *app/storage* directory not being writable by PHP

Also remember to check the Laravel logs for errors in addition to Apache error logs (Two last suggestions by @fideloper in question comments)

Answer (score 1):

If the suggestions from @marcanuy fail, you may have to add a `die('here');` statement before, and then after, each include in `index.php` to determine what is failing. If necessary, repeat this process in the included files.

I had lost the +x permission on `laravel/bootstrap`. In *nix environments this prevents you from reading the files that are in that directory.

Answer (score -1):

I had WSOD on fresh install of laravel too. It was working on my local testing machine, but not on the online server. The problem was that the online server had php 5.3 on it, after upgrading to 5.6 it worked fine.