# Lalavel 5 Give Blank White Page when upload on Shared Hosting (GoDaddy)

Tags: php, laravel-5, shared-hosting

I develop Laravel 5 app on localhost. When I upload app on shared hosting it give me blank white page. I am using PHP Version 5.5.20. mod_rewrite is active on shared hosting. Is there any way to work L5 on shared hosting. storage have the 777 permission and other folder have 755 and 644. Debug mode is set to true. Laravel is not generating any error log file. Apache log is also not showing any error. What may be the problem.

Comment: Enable debug mode to true from your application configuration and check what error exactly comes.

Comment: @AlankarMore debug mode is already true. Laravel is also not generating any error.

Comment: And please give the reason for down-vote.

Comment: I have not down voted your question.

Comment: Thank you, I have googled it a lot, after that i post it here and people down-vote it without giving any reason. How can I correct my mistake if I have done any.

Comment: I know people came here to correct the errors. But I have not down voted your question. In fact I was trying to help you.

Comment: I don't know laravel, but mostly you get blank pages or http 500 when the error logging is not set in the php.ini.

Comment: You can check your server logs.

Comment: Mbstring, OpenSSL, Mcrypt PHP extension are enabled ?

Comment: @AnandPatel Mbstring and Mcrypt PHP are enable but i do not find OpenSSL extention.

Comment: @JoginderSharma read server configuration for laravel  http://laravel.com/docs/master#server-requirements

Comment: same issue this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678360/laravel-blank-white-screen

Comment: @AnandPatel I do not know the reason but delete all file from server. run composer dump-autoload on localhost and upload all files on server again  then it work fine.

Comment: ok thats good, i think problem with autoload.php, anyways your problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the reason but delete all file from server, run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

on localhost and upload all files on server again then it work fine.