# blank page comes in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

i have setup a newly laravel 5 in my UBUNTU system which is 14.04.

when i ran my project which is http://localhost/blog/public/ it give me a blank page.
i have again and again setup laravel in my system but it not working.

i know "php artisan serve". it will run my project on http://localhost:8000/ but i don't want this. i want to run simply by entering a url. please help me and thanks a lot for your solutions.

Comment: Please check these links:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678360/laravel-blank-white-screen .  https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-50-homestead-blank-page. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-gets-a-blank-page.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: enable debug in config file

Comment: Thanks for replying but there is no errors in this project its a fresh installation. @Rasclatt

Comment: Well that is the most common for a blank page. Did you try as @anantkumarsingh suggested? Those looked pretty indepth about the same issue

Comment: yeah, i found the problem. its a permission issue. after ran this command its not working sudo chmod -R o+w storage/ at all. but after ran sudo chmod -R 777 storage, its working perfectly. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run below command on your project directory.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/
```

after this its might be working fine.

Comment: Can you explain what this does?

Comment: Basically it gives all the permission like read and on your system. where your application store the caching files or folder store them. That's why its need at least read and write permission.

Answer (score 0):

You could try any of these pointers.

- Give write permission to bootstrap/cache and storage folders

> sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache storage

- Generate new application key via the artisan command

> php artisan key:generate

- If the blank screen still persists, and you’re running on CENTOS, then it’s potentially be a SELinux issue. If so, run this command.

> setenforce permissive

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Give write permission to bootstrap/cache & storage folder by using below command

```
sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache

sudo chmod -R 777 storage
```

also make sure new application key generate. if not then use below command

```
php artisan key:generate
```