# How do I upload files into the right folder path?

Tags: apache, laravel, digital-ocean, virtual-hosts

I'm using a digital ocean Ubuntu LAMP on 14.04 , to configure let's encrypt certificate I followed this post :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04

and as a Pre-requisites I configured one domain name following this post :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Now I installed laravel 5.2 on /var/www/myblog.com ,but now I can't see any thing on my site it shows 404 error which means that there is some thing wrong with the path or the Virtual Host doesn't show php files .

I'm not exactly sure what to do or where my files should be located within Virtual Host
to be displayed properly

Comment: Laravel uses htaccess for routing. Do you have that enabled in your virtual host configuration?

Comment: no i didn't enable any htaccess routing, i only specified the directory path.                                         <VirtualHost *:80>                                                                                 ServerAdmin  ********@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/myblog.com/public
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        ServerName myblog.com
        ServerAlias www.myblog.com                                                                                     </VirtualHost>

Comment: Yes, laravel uses the url rewriting of htaccess, so it needs to enabled on the server in order for you to reach your page. I mentioned how this is done in my answer to your question, but I may have not been entirely clear that this was related to htaccess. I'm updating my answer to clearify.

Comment: still nothing is showing up even after restarting the server and forced the browser to display index.php 
could it be couse of the path 
/var/www/myblog.com/public
not exactly sure

Comment: I added a link in an edit to my answer. Have you updated the permissions on the `storage` directory yet?

Comment: i keep getting this error (chmod: cannot access ‘storage’: No such file or directory)

Comment: you need to be in the same directory as the storage directory when you run that command.

Comment: after restarting i got this error 
(AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/myblog.com/public_html] does not exist)
when i followed the post i created this folder path then i deleted and installed laravel within /var/www/myblog.com and i updated the DocumentRoot but somehow it seams to be the problem

Comment: What is the current full path to your public_html folder within your laravel installation? That is what you should set DocumentRoot to.

Comment: there is no public_html folder i deleted and installed a new laravel app and by default laravel has public folder and i modified the path to /var/www/myblog.com/public ,should i have not deleted it ? or should i rename public to public_html??

Comment: Do not rename the public folder. That will cause issues within laravel. If `/var/www/myblog.com` is the location of your laravel installation, then `DocumentRoot` should point to `/var/www/myblog.com/public`, and it sounds like it does. I think in order to fix this I will need some more information. Maybe we could pick a time to meet in chat?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel using the url rewriting features of `.htaccess`. This is quite often not the default configuration in a server installation, so you need to enable it manually, either globally, or for the particular virtual host you need it for. I would recommend you enable it only for the sites you need it on. In your virtual host configuration, make sure you include `AllowOverride All` for the directory that laravel is installed under. It will be something along the lines of this within the particular virtual host.

```
<Directory /var/www/myblog.com>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Let me know if this fixes your problem.

EDIT:

The other thing that you may not have done yet is set up the correct permissions on the `storage` directory as described in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678360/laravel-blank-white-screen).