# Laravel in subdirectory of wordpress white screen issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hello i'm trying to run a laravel app inside of a wordpress envoirement,

wordpress is here: http://example.nl

laravel is here: http://example.nl/admin

but i get a white screen and no error what so-ever,
i have debug enabled in the .env.

laravel log says nothing usefull

LARAVEL .htacces : located : http://example.nl/admin/public/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

is there something i forgot?

Any help is appreciated!
THanks

Comment: Did you check the server logs? They're usually in a subdirectory in `/var/log/`

Comment: `laravel log says nothing useful` .. you can show us :)

Comment: @S.I. it only shows logs from when the app was running locally no entries from when it was "live"

Comment: You must be getting 500 status code... please recheck.

Comment: Did you change permissions of `/storage/` directory? How did you setup paths.. what you have in `.htaccess`..for the storage permissions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678360/laravel-blank-white-screen?rq=1

Comment: @Jaimin i get no error at all, just white screen.

Comment: @S.I. i changed nothing in htacces i will upload to the post

Comment: Again, have you checked the server logs? There may be information there that will be helpful.

Comment: i will post server logs in a second

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death

Comment: @S.I. added server logs

Comment: Now you see the error `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'...`

Comment: What version of PHP is running on the server? It looks like it's trying to use PHP7 code on a PHP5 server.

Comment: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16 @aynber .... is this the problem?

Comment: `::class` it's only available in PHP versions 5.5 and above

Comment: Yes. Per Laravel's site:  Laravel 5.1 requires PHP 5.5.9 or greater. Laravel 5.3 requires PHP 5.6.4 or higher.

Comment: Allright guys, Thanks alot. i will close this post now. thank you!!!

Comment: You can edit it with note below what was the problem for future users.

Comment: Allright will do thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`::class`** is only available in **PHP5.5** and above.

My server had `X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16`.