# php version 5.6.4 different 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I made a Laravel 5.3 website in PHP version 5.6.4, but my host is only providing 5.6, 5.5 and 7.0. The website I made isn't running on the server. Are these versions so different that it does not support PHP version 5.6 if built in 5.6.4?

Comment: I read in another comment that you uploaded your website (all folders and files) to the public_html folder of your webhosting. Can you upload all of the contents of the public folder from your Laravel project into the public_html folder of your webhosting and upload the rest of the files one folder up? The public folder of laravel is meant to be the public_html folder of your webhosting.

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel 5.3 version working on apache 5.6 version as well as 5.5 version**

Make some changes in your laravel application

1. Change server.php on root to index.php
2. Copy .htaccess file from public folder and put it into root folder

Now run your application with server url

> TRY this :-

Try this, in the public/index.php page

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Comment: i will try and let you know.

Comment: ok so i made a new laravel website.uploaded it into public_html.changed the name of server.php to index.php and brought the .htaccess from /home/public_html/public to public_html/.and it still does not work.

Comment: no there is no 500 error.it just shows a blank white page.i am not even uploading my project.i am trying a default laravel website that laravel creates for us and it still does not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678360/laravel-blank-white-screen please check

Comment: Try error reporting in index page ..to getting error