# Homestead/Laravel shows a white page after installing LDAP

Tags: php, laravel, ldap, vagrant, homestead

I am using a `Homestead` and installed `ldap` for `php` as `vagrant` like this:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-ldap
```

I had the error:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68
```

I checked the typical errors even though the login worked before installing `LDAP`. There is a `{{ csrf_token() }}`, the `storage/framework/sessions` has 777 permit, I have cleared the cache but nothing works.

So I reset `Homestead` and get to the login page, which works.

But when I login now the page is completely white and there is nothing in the log at all.

I have tried to do a `dd("hello")` in the login controller but it is never called either. It just does not go to the controller after installing `LDAP`.

As I said before, it works if I am not logged in.

Comment: Have a look in /var/log/nginx/yoursitename-error.log there might be some errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel blank white screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678360/laravel-blank-white-screen)

Comment: @Dominik Somehow the installation messed up the permits... thanks it works again.

Comment: Good to hear! Please provide the actions you have taken as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that after installing LDAP all permits were changed.

I just set them back recursively:

```
sudo chown -R www-data /path/to/laravel/files
```

Now everything works fine again.