# Laravel Error 403 after changing OS

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel, laravel-4, lamp

I just have changed my OS from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 14.04.

On windows 7 I've been working in a project in Laravel.

After I changed to Ubuntu, installed lamp and other stuff, I could manage to run a Laravel test Project. (var/www/html/laraveltest)

But when I copy the folder of my project (var/www/html/myproject) I get the message Forbidden 403. I got this message in every url like 
    `http://localhost/myproject/public`, `http://localhost/myproject/public/home` etc.

I tried deleting the vendor folder and re-installing composer again but doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the file permissions in your /var/www/html/myproject folder .. the files have to be readable by the user running the webserver (e.g. nobody for apache) or even writable for file caches

Comment: You may want to check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481660/403-error-on-apache-for-a-laravel-project-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-13-10