# White blank pages in Laravel After Login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Sorry, this is question don't have a code snippet but a situation. I've a Laravel application which was running fine on my localhost and server. Today I made some updates to the controllers and some views. The changes was working fine in the localhost. So I uploaded the files to the server. But when I tried to login in the server, I could see the home page, login pages and all. But getting a white blank page after login.

When I manually try to navigate to other pages in the logged in section, it redirects to the dashboard and blank page comes. Everything is working fine in the localhost. I didn't make any updates to the server configuration. Everything was as before.

`OS: CentOS 6.6 (Final)`
`PHP version: 5.6`
`Laravel 4.2`
`Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)`

I checked several answers from other similar questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678360/laravel-blank-white-screen) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481660/403-error-on-apache-for-a-laravel-project-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-13-10/19482358#19482358). But they all had some updating situation. But in my case not so.

What would be the problem? If you need any additional information, just let me know.

I can give some more information:

When I access a course page (which I need to login to see), it shows a 302 Found status code in the Network tab and then redirects to the Login page where it again shows a 302 Found status code and then to the dashboard with a 200 ok code. Session is being created. Thats' why  it's redirecting back to the dashboard page. But the page is still empty.

Comment: Is there anything showing up in your laravel.log file?

Comment: No, nothing in the laravel.log file.

Comment: @lukasgeiter, Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

A blank white screen usually means either

1. Your'e rendering a template with no content
2. A fatal PHP occurred **before** Laravel could completely bootstrap itself

The "right" thing to do here is to check your web server error logs, or your PHP error logs.  I'm going to guess you don't know where those are or if they're setup properly.  If that's the case you'll want to temporarily change PHP's `display_error` ini setting.  In Laravel 4.2 I'd do this by setting the ini in the following file

```
#File: boostrap/start.php
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors','1');
    //... rest of file
```

This should result in the error being displayed on the screen, and from there you can debug further.

Comment: I did this and tried to access the account page (after login). Still shows the same blank page with no errors.

Comment: I can give some more information: <br><br>

When I access a course page (which I need to login to see), it shows a 302 Found status code in the Network tab and then redirects to the Login page where it again shows a 302 Found status code and then to the dashboard with a 200 ok code. Session is being created. Thats' why  it's redirecting back to the dashboard page. But the page is still empty.